# how to return a detail information of URL/author from cidoc crm rdf file using sparql

Tags: java, eclipse, rdf, sparql, jena

Thank you for the answer but unfortunately i am not getting any result in the console, here i am attaching my code, please guide that where i am making a mistake.

```
 FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(test.class.getClassLoader());
          Model model=FileManager.get().loadModel("H:/EclipseWorkplace/MuseumDatabaseRecommendation/src/data3.rdf");
String spr="prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"+ 
        "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"+
        "prefix crm:  <urn:x-stackoverflow:example#>\n"+
        "\n"+
        "SELECT * WHERE{\n"+
        "   [ crm:E21_Person/rdfs:label ?creator\n"+
        "   ; crm:P108i_was_produced_by [ crm:P126_employed [ rdfs:label ?material ]\n"+
        "                               ; crm:P4_has_time-span [ crm:P82_at_some_time_within ?timespan ]\n"+
        "                               ]\n"+
        "   ; crm:P3_has_note [ a crm:P102_has_title\n"+
        "                     ; rdfs:label ?title\n"+
        "                     ]\n"+
        "   ]\n"+
        "  FILTER( ?creator = \"Brett WHITELEY\" ).\n"+
        "}";

Query query = QueryFactory.create(spr); //s2 = the query above
QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.create(  query,model );
//QueryExecution qExe = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService( "http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query );
ResultSet results = qExe.execSelect();
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);
```

My current output is

```
-----------------------------------------
| creator | material | timespan | title |
=========================================
-----------------------------------------
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The code provided does not compile (queryString is not defined, unescaped quotes(`"`), etc). You also would greatly assist us by adding a small example input file that you expect to get results from.

Comment: "I don't know how to get it from an RDF file using sparql" - there are several good SPARQL tutorials out on the Web, which should help you figure this out. Or if you already have tried some SPARQL queries and got stuck, please share what you have sofar and why it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Query1- SELECT * WHERE { ?s  rdfs:label ?'Brett WHITELEY'  } LIMIT 10                                                                Query2- SELECT * WHERE { ?o rdf:type ?'Painting';   } LIMIT 10 from both queries i have received an ID of that node which is a URL but i want to get every information, i have used '*' so i thought i would be able to get everything but nope its not working like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Input Data**

In order to facilitate readability, I restructured your model into `TURTLE` syntax for others to read.

```
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix crm:   <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/> .

<http://phdprototype.tk/collectionimage   /4D0BFF17-5810-4644-A550-D35EE090D4A8.png>
        a                          "Painting" ;
        rdfs:label                 "Brett WHITELEY" ;
        crm:E21_Person             [ a           <E39_Actor> ;
                                     rdfs:label  "Brett WHITELEY"
                                   ] ;
        crm:E62_String             "Painting\n" ;
        crm:P108i_was_produced_by  [ a                     crm:E12_Production ;
                                     crm:P126_employed     [ a           crm:E57_Material ;
                                                             rdfs:label  "Oil"
                                                           ] ;
                                     crm:P4_has_time-span  [ a                            crm:E52_Time-Span ;
                                                             crm:P82_at_some_time_within  "\n      1976\n    "
                                                           ]
                                   ] ;
        crm:P3_has_note            [ a           crm:P102_has_title ;
                                     rdfs:label  "Interior with Time Past"
                                   ] ;
        crm:P7_took_place_at       [ a                          crm:E53_Place ;
                                     crm:E44_Place_Appellation  "    \n    5D\n    "
                                   ] ;
        crm:P91_has_unit           [ a           crm:E58_Measurement_Unit ;
                                     rdfs:label  "182.0 h * 200.0 w cm"
                                   ] .
```

There are some issues with this data. For example, your painting has `rdf:type` the plain literal `"painting"`, which is extremely bad. This is denoted by the `a "painting"` property-object pair. We can execute a query over this data, but you may wish to restructure your ontology so that it uses terms like `rdf:type` properly.

**Query**

For the sample data provided, the following query will extract what you are looking for:

```
prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
prefix crm:  <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>

SELECT * WHERE{
   [ crm:E21_Person/rdfs:label ?creator
   ; crm:P108i_was_produced_by [ crm:P126_employed [ rdfs:label ?material ]
                               ; crm:P4_has_time-span [ crm:P82_at_some_time_within ?timespan ]
                               ]
   ; crm:P3_has_note [ a crm:P102_has_title
                     ; rdfs:label ?title
                     ]
   ]
  FILTER( ?creator = "Brett WHITELEY" ).
}
```

will result in:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| creator          | material | timespan             | title                     |
==================================================================================
| "Brett WHITELEY" | "Oil"    | "\n      1976\n    " | "Interior with Time Past" |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that this is highly tailored to your particular sample data. You will need to adjust this query to match what structures are actually allowed. For (hypothetical) example, the `TimeSpan` instance may sometimes have a `crm:P82_at_some_time_span` property, or it may have some `crm:exampleProperty` that relates it to another values. In that case, you'd need to modify the query to use a property path to match this.

**Example Code**

```
public static final String queryString = "prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"+ 
        "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n"+
        "prefix crm:  <http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/>\n"+
        "\n"+
        "SELECT * WHERE{\n"+
        "   [ crm:E21_Person/rdfs:label ?creator\n"+
        "   ; crm:P108i_was_produced_by [ crm:P126_employed [ rdfs:label ?material ]\n"+
        "                               ; crm:P4_has_time-span [ crm:P82_at_some_time_within ?timespan ]\n"+
        "                               ]\n"+
        "   ; crm:P3_has_note [ a crm:P102_has_title\n"+
        "                     ; rdfs:label ?title\n"+
        "                     ]\n"+
        "   ]\n"+
        "  FILTER( ?creator = \"Brett WHITELEY\" ).\n"+
        "}";
public static final Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {

    final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
    try( final InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/so.rdf") ) {
        model.read(in, null, "RDF/XML");
    }
    model.write(System.out, "TTL");
    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    System.out.println(queryString);
    System.out.println("=================================================================");
    try( final QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) ) {
        ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, exec.execSelect(), query);
    }

}
```

Comment: A note in addition to the one about `rdf:type` values, it's probably better to use `values ?creator { "Brett WHITELEY" }` than `filter ( ?creator = "Brett WHITELEY" )`.   A good engine should optimize, but a less-good one may do better with the `values` block.

Comment: (That said, it *is* usually a good idea to make minimal changes to illustrate the difference, so it's not a bad idea to leave the filter as it was.)